# Liferay: expiration date for messages (message board)

Tags: java, liferay

Am I just missing something obvious, or is there no reasonable or halfway feasible way to add an expiration date to messages in Liferay's message board?

The first problem is how to enter the expiration date in the message editor. The most obvious solution is perhaps an expando attribute, but there seem to be no expando data type for dates (only date & time) and I find no way to set a calculated default value in the expando attribute (e.g. today + 6 months). Even without a default value, a date+time attribute defaults to Jan 1st 1970, 0:00GMT and using the date picker to enter a real expiration date is rather tedious. After entering the expiration date, there is no obvious way to validate it (e.g. restrict it to dates between today and today + 6 months) and when the date is displayed in the message view, the current locale is not used to format the date and time.

Even if I would somehow manage to squeeze the expiration date into an expando attribute, there is further no obvious way to evaluate the expiration date.

It would have been acceptable that the messages are still persisted, but not counted and shown in the MB portlet. The methods in MBThreadServiceUtil to access the messages does however not offer any additional filtering criterias, so I either have to load all messages and do the count/filter operations in Java code (hardly a very clever solution) or I would have to rewrite the entire service stack "bottom-up" and add get or search methods, which are able to forward the filtering to the database.

The preferred solution would be to have a scheduled task, which regularly deletes expired messages completely. Since the MB portlet is supporting scopes (the messages are related to the portlet's scope) and the scheduled task is not run within a portlet context, I would have to get access to the scope id somehow. If I understand the documentation and available discussions on this topic, the default scope should be the community, to which the page belongs. Our "message board page" is on the other hand added on the organization level, and the messages' scope id does not match either the organization id, nor any of the ids of the communities in the organization. Anyone with an idea on how to determine the scope id in this case?

Comment: Which version of Liferay are you using 6.0 or 6.1? Also I guess you have scoped the portlet to the page through the Configuration pop-up --> Scope --> changed the select drop-down to Current Page, is this case?

Comment: We are using 6.0.5 CE. The portlet is scoped to the "default scope" and not to the page.

Answer (score 1):

I would it make with scheduled task - liferay use herefor Quartz;
http://liferaysnippets.com/how-to-create-cron-job-in-liferay/

The expired Messages you can hold with DynamicQueries:

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -6);
    Date halfYearAgo = c.getTime();
    ClassLoader portalClassLoader = PortalClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader();
    DynamicQuery query = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(MBThread.class, portalClassLoader)
            .add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("lastPostDate").le(halfYearAgo)).addOrder(OrderFactoryUtil.asc("lastPostDate"));

    try {
        List dynamicQuery = MBThreadLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(query);
        for (Object object : dynamicQuery) {
            MBThread thread = (MBThread) object;
            MBThreadLocalServiceUtil.deleteMBThread(thread);
        }
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This does not really answer my question. It deletes the threads based on the last post date and not based on a configurable expiration date. For some reason, I have MBThread entities, which do not come from the message board portlet, so even if I would delete based on the last post date, I would need an additional criteria with the correct scope (see the last paragraph in my question on the problem with determining the correct scope).

Comment: ok, then, you can create an expando attribute and add this programmaticaly to MBThread, when the current page is in the required scope. You can do this with "value.object.listener.com.liferay.portlet.messageboards.model.MBThread=com.my.MyChanger" property. Implement the methode "onAfterCreate(MBThread mbThread) ...